# Universal Image Loader not caching correctly

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

In my main activity, I have a viewpager that loads the images my using UIL. When I sign in my first account, it displays 5 images and downloaded them correctly (created 5 files in my cache folder). I tried logging in again and yes, images were loaded from the disc.

When I signed in my 2nd account, it loads 5 images and has 4 same images with the first account so I was expecting that it will just create 1 file in my cache folder. However, UIL created another 5 files.

Here are the contents of the cache directory after logging those 2 accounts:

```
2 copies of 20 KB file
2 copies of 76 KB file
2 copies of 204 KB file
2 copies of 84 KB file
1 copy of 34 KB file
1 copy of 46 KB file
```

Here is the configuration of my image loader:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getApplicationContext(), "/cache");
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .writeDebugLogs()
        .build();

imageLoader.init(config);
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
         .cacheInMemory(true)
         .cacheOnDisc(true)
         .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
         .build();
```

How I use UIL on the viewpager's adapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_item, container,false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    display(img, list.get(position), progressBar); //list contains the urls
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, App.options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            //progress bar changing visibility
        } );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the images were downloaded from different urls. It was the fault of the web developer, he used different links even if the images are the same..